# Am loading column which is a varchar storing JSON string from mysql table into Spark dataframe. I would like to be able to use Spark Sql on it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is how my code

```
    val query = """
    (select id, data as b_data from gtest) t
    """

    val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.22:3306/db")
      .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
      .option("useSSL", "false")
      .option("user", "dba")
      .option("password", "pwd")
      .option("dbtable",query)
      .load()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")
```

Field b_data in the mysql table tbl is of varchar type and has JSON that looks like the below(just a sample), it can get nested, and I would like to be able to use this JSON without having to use a fixed schema as defining the schema manually is not practical as the JSON can be large and nested.

```
{"id" : 100, "details" : {"fn" : "sample", "ln" : "data"}}
```

What I would like be able do is the following

```
%sql
select id, b_data.id, b_data.details.fn from tbl
```

Some Information

```
df.printSchema

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- b_data: string (nullable = true)
```

```
spark.version

res89: String = 2.4.5
```

The Exception i get when i run the sql query is as below

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
....
....
....

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from b_data#4270: need struct type but got string; line 1 pos 10
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:73)
......
```

I assume the DataFrame's column type has to be changed from String to a DataStruct?? I am lost at this point.

Comment: can you share the schema of `df` with `df.printSchema`?

Comment: It is already there in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Datatype of `b_data` is String (JSON string) so you are not able to query it.
You may want to read the json string before you create temp view.

You can provide the custom schema while reading or you can get the schema with `schema_of_json` function

```
val schema = schema_of_json(lit(df.select($"b_data").as[String].first))
val resultDF = df.withColumn("b_data_new", from_json($"b_data", schema))

resultDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl")
```

Now you can query as

```
select b_data_new.id, b_data_new.details.fn from tbl
```